# Justification for the generating function equality in the derivation of the Bernoulli-Seki formula

Tags: generating-functions

In the derivation of the Bernoulli-Seki formula the first step is unfolding the exponential generating function of $S_n(k)=\sum_{a=1}^k a^n$
as
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} S_n(k) \frac{T^n}{n !}=\sum_{a=1}^k \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(a T)^n}{n !}=\sum_{a=1}^k e^{a T}=e^T \frac{e^{k T}-1}{e^T-1}
$$

This part is clear.

However, I don't follow the equality

$$\frac{T e^T}{e^T-1}=\sum_{m \geq 0} B_m \frac{T^m} {m !}$$

in

$$
e^T \frac{e^{k T}-1}{e^T-1}=\frac{T e^T}{e^T-1} \cdot \frac{e^{k T}-1}{T}=\left(\sum_{m \geq 0} B_m \frac{T^m}{m !}\right)\left(\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{k^{n+1} T^n}{(n+1) !}\right)
$$

with $B_m$ being the corresponding Bernoulli number.

I get that it is a definition, but the coefficients (Bernoulli numbers) are already embedded in an algebraic expression in the RHS. **How is it guaranteed that such a generating function exists at all?**

I see now that

$$\frac{e^{kT}-1}{T}=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{k^{n+1} T^n}{(n+1)!}\\=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{k^{n+1} T^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac 1 T=\left(e^{kT}-1\right)\frac 1 T$$

---

The question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456177/152225).

Comment: The first is a definition of Bernoulli numbers the second cones from the definition of exponential.

Comment: @lcv Yes, the second one was quite easy. How is the existence of the GF in the first part a given? How is it obvious that such an expression would work at all?

Comment: Yes good job (your updated question).